# Bump Connects and Disconnects involuntarily - iOS

Tags: ios, bump

I have implemented Bump Api 3.0 in my new iOS app. It works fine, I can transfer images which are less than 20KB and also strings and dictionaries.

The real problem is that, the Bump gets connected and disconnected without notice.
I have the Demo version Key for Bump as of now. Does this happens only in Demo Api key?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bump SDK have the session Management in the application when application starts the bump session its ready to bump and at this time if bump event occur then its transfer the data successfully to another device. Bump have "shared instance" means shared equally for whole application at the time of bump. So there is requirement to close the bump session . Then we called here endsession for the bump object in the event of bump techniques.

After that if bump event occur then there is no transfer of data to another device as bump session is not active. I used these stuffs in my card swapping application uses the bump technology.

There is no problem due to demo keys (development keys) or anything.